# Switch between DVI and VGA

Tags: c#, monitor, vga, dvi

Is there a way of switching the monitor's input from VGA to DVI programmatically in C# ?
I've found an article on how to switch it on or off [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12794/Complete-Guide-on-How-To-Turn-A-Monitor-On-Off-Sta). Any suggestions ?

Comment: I doubt it, since when were computer monitors ever programmable? They only take in video/audio signals. You have to change the inputs on the device itself.

Comment: yes but enTech's mControl does it...

Comment: If that's the case then you have to work with _their_ APIs, this feature doesn't come standard.